# long gc collection in java when changing boolean variable from a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, garbage-collection

Weird issue I encountered, and took me long time to isolate the cause of it,
I have a class which starts a simple thread:

```
public class ServerConnector implements Handler {

private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ImagePackage> queue;
private  boolean isDuringSend;
private String requestId;
private boolean isRunning;
private boolean done;
private ImagePackage packet;
private Context context;

public ServerConnector(Context context) {
    packet = null;
    this.context = context;
    done = false;
    requestId = null;
    isDuringSend = false;
    queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ImagePackage>();
}

public void add(ImagePackage packet) {
    if (packet.getImage() != null) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.add(packet);
            queue.notifyAll();
        }

    }

}

public void start() {
    isRunning = true;

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        ImagePackage packet = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (isRunning) {
                if (!isDuringSend) {

                    packet = getElementFromQueue();
                    if (packet == null) {

                        continue;
                    }

                    try {


                        isDuringSend = true;
                    //  processQueue(packet);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                LoadingActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        isDuringSend = false;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

}
```

now the GC works and it takes him 300 ms to clear everything up:

```
  12-29 23:41:06.937: D/dalvikvm(14102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 16% free 13788K/16244K, paused                    271ms, total 271ms
  12-29 23:41:07.257: D/dalvikvm(14102): JIT unchain all for threadid=16
  12-29 23:41:07.287: D/dalvikvm(14102): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 69K, 6% free 15289K/16244K, paused 270ms, total 272ms
  12-29 23:41:07.567: D/dalvikvm(14102): JIT unchain all for threadid=16 
  12-29 23:41:07.848: D/dalvikvm(14102): JIT unchain all for threadid=16
  12  -29 23:41:07.868: D/dalvikvm(14102): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3036K, 21% free 13858K/17460K,   paused   254ms+256ms, total 545ms
```

but when I remove this simple line "is during send = false" from the code which is basically just switching a boolean field to true from inside the thread, the GC clean time will be reduced to ~ 40ms.

any ideas please why it happens?

```
public void start() {
    isRunning = true;

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        ImagePackage packet = null;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (isRunning) {
                if (!isDuringSend) {

                    packet = getElementFromQueue();
                    if (packet == null) {

                        continue;
                    }

                    try {


                        isDuringSend = true;
                    //  processQueue(packet);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Comment: looks like your thread is very CPU intensive and GC takes more time because of this

Comment: why would it be a CPU intensive? more than that, if I allocate new object from inside the thread, the GC will clean it quite fast, even though it "cost" more memory, its only that boolean which is a field in the serverconnector class that caused it

Answer (score 0):

I Had a similar issue where the GC was causing lags on my app, it was solved adding "volatile" to the variable that can be changed from another thread, in your case it would be the "isDuringSend" var.

In my case i had no idea what was causing this, so your question really helped me to track down the issue.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that my post helped you :), it is indeed a strange issue which I still didn't figure out.